# Why do I need to initialize the struct with self.init() even if I assign all of the properties?

Tags: swift, struct, init

In `simd_float4x4`, `columns` is the only property, however, this won't work solely because I'm not calling `self.init()`. Everything would have been initialize anyway. Why is the compiler complaining? I saw something similar in [this](https://youtu.be/3Mo8fUoxCgk?t=468) video, and it was working. Why can't I do it?

```
extension simd_float4x4 {
    init(ProjectionFrame: CGSize) {
        let Y = FOV(), FarZ = Float((Settings.VisibilityRange+1)*2), Z = FarZ / (NearZ - FarZ)
        columns = (vector_float4(Y / Float(ProjectionFrame.width / ProjectionFrame.height), 0, 0, 0), vector_float4(0, Y, 0, 0), vector_float4(0, 0, Z, -1), vector_float4(0, 0, Z * NearZ, 0))
    }
}
```

In the video I noticed this.

```
extension simd_float4x4 {
    init(translationX x: Float, x: Float, x: Float) {
        columns = (
            vector_float4(x, 0, 0, 0),
            vector_float4(0, x, 0, 0),
            vector_float4(0, 0, x, 0),
            vector_float4(0, 0, 0, 1)
        )
    }
}
```

And the compiler wasn't complaining. How come it's complaining for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to set `columns` from your `init`, you should just call `self.init(_ columns:)` and pass in the 4 `vector_float4`s as an `Array` rather than as a `tuple`.

```
extension simd_float4x4 {
    init(ProjectionFrame: CGSize) {
        let Y = FOV(), FarZ = Float((Settings.VisibilityRange+1)*2), Z = FarZ / (NearZ - FarZ)
        self.init([vector_float4(Y / Float(ProjectionFrame.width / ProjectionFrame.height), 0, 0, 0), vector_float4(0, Y, 0, 0), vector_float4(0, 0, Z, -1), vector_float4(0, 0, Z * NearZ, 0)])
    }
}
```

That video is 2 years old and hence uses an older Swift version. The code you link from that video also doesn't compile in Swift 5.

Unrelated to your question, but variable names in Swift should be lowerCamelCase, so `projectionFrame` is the correct naming.

Comment: @user393334 that video is 2 years old, using an old Swift version. Directly initialising properties isn't allowed anymore, you need to delegate to another initialiser now.

Comment: I didn't like that change at all

Comment: Aslo, why exactly should I pass an array instead of a tuple? What difference does it make?

Comment: Also, why did they feel that directly initializing properties was a feature that was necessary to remove?

Comment: There may be other pre-conditions that the initializer enforces. "Set the properties to exactly the passed values" is not the only thing that an initializer can do. For example, an initializer might clamp `let` values to some range, ensuring that the rest of the code can assume that the value will always be in that range. If you bypass the initializer, that precondition can be violated

Comment: @user393334 Structs aren't bags of properties, and if you try to force that mental model on them, you'll have a hard time. By ensuring that parent initializers are called, structs can enforce invariants that would be impossible to uphold if people could just initialize them as a bag of values.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica As a C programmer, now using Swift because to my knowledge Metal can't be programmed directly in C, I'm inclined to think of structs as bags of properties, but in Swift they're more than that I guess

Comment: But why should I pass an array instead of a tuple?

Comment: @user393334 They're more like opaque pointers in C. They can encapsulate invariants and protect them. That would be impossible if someone can just side-step the initialize, and for-example, instantiate a `Kernel` whose with a matrix values aren't normalized, thereby fucking over every bit of consumer code that relies on the matrix being normalized.

Comment: @user393334 because the initialiser takes an array, so you need to pass it an array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively I could bridge it to C

```c
#include <simd/simd.h>
matrix_float4x4 ProjectPerspective(const float Ratio) {
    const float Y = 1/tanf(Rad(Settings.FOV+15)), FarZ = (Settings.VisibilityRange+1)*32, Z = FarZ/(NearZ-FarZ);
    return (matrix_float4x4){.columns = {{Y/Ratio, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Y, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Z, -1}, {0, 0, Z*NearZ, 0}}};
}
```